# Не работает запрос TRUNCATE TABLE к SQL Server Compact CE

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

Создал консольное приложение, через NuGet добавил необходимые dll для работы с базой (System.Data.SqlServerCe версии 4.0.0.0)

Программно база создается, в обозревателе серверов ее можно открыть, все без ошибок, но проблема в том что не могу выполнить ни один запрос (таблица Items есть, создал руками через подключение в обозревателе серверов).

```
    string ConnectionStr = @"Data source = test.sdf";
    //SqlCeEngine en = new SqlCeEngine(ConnectionStr);
    //en.CreateDatabase();

    SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand();
    cmd.Connection = new SqlCeConnection(ConnectionStr);
    cmd.Connection.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = "TRUNCATE TABLE Items";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd.Connection.Close();
```

Выпадает ошибка на `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` -

> Необработанное исключение типа
>   "System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException" в System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll

В просмотре сведений -

> {"Ошибка при разборе запроса. [ Token line number = 1,Token line
>   offset = 1,Token in error = TRUNCATE ]"}

Пробовал и так `cmd.CommandText = "TRUNCATE TABLE [Items]";` - аналогично.

Answer (score 1):

Жаль, но там не поддерживается эта конструкция.
Используйте вместо неё вот это:

```
DELETE FROM [Table]
ALTER TABLE [Table] ALTER COLUMN [ID] IDENTITY (1,1)
```

Comment: Почему тогда когда я использую System.Data.SqlServerCe 3.5.1.0 все работает??? Я про truncate table

Comment: Даже если я изменю запрос на Create Table ... и тд - аналогичная ошибка

Comment: Понятия не имею, может в ранней версии она была, а потом её убрали.

Comment: Допустим убрали, а как быть с Create Table и прочими командами?

Comment: @e1s Ну у вас какая-то мелкая ошибка в синтаксисе скорее всего, не могу понять сходу, так как вы не указали код для создания таблицы.

Comment: Видимо дело не в ошибке - DELETE FROM очищает таблицу